# R write table creates extra blank row

Tags: r, csv, export-to-csv

When I run this R code, it creates a CSV file with an extra blank row at the end of the file and that is causing some issues in other programs that use the file. Is this a known issue? Is there a way to prevent R from adding an extra blank row at the end?

```
x <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
y <- c(1,2,3,6,8)
my.data <- data.frame(x, y)
write.table(my.data, file="mydata.csv",eol="\n", quote=FALSE, sep=',', row.names = FALSE, col.names = c("one","two"))
```

Comment: Question, how do you know there is an extra row? Do you open the .csv file and check? Because I don't see it.

Comment: Interesting, never noticed that. I get the same thing. You can always open it in R studio and delete it. But probably not what you want :D  I tried deleting `eol` but didnt help. Neither does using `write.csv`

Comment: @JanSila Yeah, me too. I've been working with these forever, but I ran into a program that finally detected the blank row. I think it's just how R creates them, but very few programs have an issue with them so most people don't notice it

Comment: I guess it must be that the underlying code starts a new line, reads the next line to write and if it is empty it finishes, but hard to say really. Maybe somebody will know. Upvote for interesting problem on a Friday night :)

Comment: Weird, using `readr::format_csv(my.data)` the result is `"x,y\n1.0,1.0\n2.0,2.0\n3.0,3.0\n4.0,6.0\n5.0,8.0\n"`. I tried to save as `write("x,y\n1.0,1.0\n2.0,2.0\n3.0,3.0\n4.0,6.0\n5.0,8.0","mydata.csv")` and extra line appears again.